Paraphrase the question on the topic of elementary set theory
I don't understand what's asked in the following problem:
Proof that if any equation (containing variables for sets and $\bigcup$ , $\bigcap$ and $/$ ) is not true one can find a counterexample in which sets are empty or contain one element.
I ask the site users to help me to understand the problem.

Can you share more context? Where is the problem taken from or related details?

The problem is taken from a Russian elementary set-theory textbook written by Shen and Vereshchagin. No more details are given and it's just a problem at the end of the paragraph.

I remember this problem, from my first logic class. The problem asks you to consider the class of all set theoretic universally quantified equations including only variables for sets, unions, intersections, and minuses, (and parentheses).   The true equations are usually called identities.
For example, $$\forall A,B \;A \cap B=A\setminus (A \setminus B)$$
is an equation in this class, in fact it is an identity.
The problem statement is: For any false statement in this class, show that there is a counter example where all sets referred to in the equations contain one element or less.
For example $$\forall A,B \; A \cup B = A \cap B$$ is false because:
$$A= \{ 1 \}, B=\emptyset$$
is a counter example.
Here is how I would approach this. What does it mean for two sets to be unequal? It means there is an element in one which is not in the other.
That means that, given any counterexample, we can reduce all sets in it to their subsets containing just that element, otherwise the empty set. See if you can show that our reduced example is indeed a counterexample.
